# How do I get the proper output for the color bands of a 3 band resistor?

Tags: c

I am taking a programming class as an elective. Our current lab is to create a program that accepts a number from the user that represents a resistor band. The max would be two digits followed by 9 zeros; 11 total digits. After accepting the number I have a few functions that find the first two digits, then the modulus for the second band and divide by 10 for the first. My issue lies in using a logarithm 10 function and even trying a loop with a counter to find the number of zeros. I have gotten it to be able to count 8 zeros, but once the ninth gets added it messes everything up including the first number. In my code I have some instruction or information and some functions stagnant as I hid them to try different options. I currently have just been trying to be able to enter 99000000000 and get "White" in return for all three numbers. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include "math.h"

    long int inputValue();
    void outputColor(int);
    int bandCalc(long int);
    int loop(long int);
    int divideResistor(int);
    // function prototypes // '''


    int main()
    {
        int resistor, x, y, z, a, b, c, f;

        resistor = inputValue();
            //printf("\n\tThe resistor value is %d", resistor);//
        c = resistor;

        b = divideResistor(resistor);

        f = loop(b);
            //printf("\t\nThe number is %d", b);//


        if (f <= 10)
        {
            f = log10(c) - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            f = log10(c) - 2;
        }

        //Here we are finding out how many zeros there are in the number//
        printf("\n\tThe character x equals %d", x);

            y = bandCalc(b); //Here we are getting the first two digits of the resistor value//
        printf("\n\tThe character y equals %d", y);

            z = fmod(y, 10); //Here we are finding the second digit of the resistor//
        printf("\n\tThe character z equals %d", z);

            a = (y / 10); //Here we are finding the first digit of the resistor//
        printf("\n\tThe character a equals %d", a);

        x = bandCalc(resistor);
        printf("\n\tThe returned number is %d", x);


            printf("\n\n\tThe color of the resistor bands are: \n\n");

        printf("\n\t");
        outputColor(a); 
        printf("\t    ");
        outputColor(z); 
        printf("\t    ");
        outputColor(f); 

        system("pause>nul");

        return 0;
    }
    int divideResistor(int s)
    {
        s = s / 10;
        return (s);
    }
    int loop(long int j)
    {
        int k;
        k = 0;
        if (j >= 100)
    }
}
        j /= 10;
        k++;

        for (j > 100; j /= 10; k++)
        k <= 9;
        printf("%d ", k);

        return (k);
    }

     long int inputValue()

    {
        long int band = 0;

        printf("\nPlease enter the value of the resistor band: ");
        scanf("%d", &band); 
        return (band);
    }

    int bandCalc(long int z)
    {
        long n = z;
        long n1 = n, n2 = n;
        while (n)
        {
            n2 = n1;
            n1 = n;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return (n2);
     }

    void outputColor(int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {   
            case 0:
            printf("   Black");
            break;
            case 1:
            printf("   Brown");
            break;
            case 2:
            printf("   Red");
            break;
            case 3:
            printf("   Orange");
            break;
            case 4:
            printf("   Yellow");
            break;
            case 5:
            printf("   Green");
            break;
            case 6:
            printf("   Blue");
            break;
            case 7:
            printf("   Violet");
            break;
            case 8:
            printf("   Grey");
            break;
            case 9:
            printf("   White");
            break;
        //return (band);//
        }

    }
```

Comment: I had a little trouble uploading the code, so there are some functions that I had tried out but hid through the process to try and get each function to work properly.

Comment: Is your datatype capable of storing large-enough values?

Comment: Yes. We are using what our instructor told us to use. But of course we are only able to use what we have learned., so matrix, vectors and arrays aren't allowed. When I run the program and input 12 and eight zeros I get Brown Red Grey" which is what I want but when I try nine zeros for white it doesn't matter what the first two digits are, my results are all different colors that no longer match the number.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your inputValue function:

```
long int inputValue()
{
    long int band = 0;

    printf("\nPlease enter the value of the resistor band: ");
    scanf("%d", &band); // format-specifier for a "long int" is "%ld"
    return (band);
}
```

You are using a `long` to store the input, but you are telling `scanf` that `band` is only an `int`, so it will only be able to store values as high as `INT_MAX` (2147483647 for 32-bit two's complement `int`s).  Assuming `long` is a 64-bit type on your system, it will be able to handle much larger values (9223372036854775807).

Try fixing your `scanf` call there to use the `%ld` format-specifier: `scanf("%ld", &band);`

Similarly, look at the type of `resistor` which takes the return of `inputValue`. It is of type `int`, so it won't be able to handle values that are outside of that `INT_MAX` range.  That should also be type `long`.  You'll also need to modify the input of functions such as `divideResistor` to take a `long`.

Beyond the issues of not using large enough integer types, you are also using floating-point operations on integer-type data. which can create rounding errors.  `log10`, for example, is meant to handle `double` types.  `fmod` is also intended for `double` types (the `%` operator is used do perform 'modulo' operations on integer types)

There may be further errors beyond these.  If you find yourself having more trouble, please give [this link](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a look-over and see if it helps you to help yourself, or at least help you construct a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of specific issues rather than a scavenger hunt to find all the errors in your full program.

Comment: I made that adjustment. I hid all functions except for the one to count the zeros. When I enter 99000000000, I'm expecting "White" but I'm getting "Violet". So I am losing 2 somewhere. When I enter 9900000000, I get "Grey" which is still correct.

Comment: You have more places where you are not using large-enough data-types.  See my edit.

Comment: `long` does not *guarantee* 64-bit but `long long` does. Generally I can't see any reason to use `long` .

Comment: @WeatherVane I do not disagree with you (I did specify an *assumption* on 64-bit long), however the OP said in a comment above that the data-types used are what they were instructed to use, so for the purpose of this answer, I am sticking with `long`.  In the real world, I would probably elect to use `uint_least64_t` (I don't believe there should be any negative values when dealing with resistor bands).

Comment: That's fair enough.

Comment: I made those changes as well and tried long long. When I enter 99000000000 I am getting back red (=2), brown (=1) and violet (=7)

Comment: The program is giving me the correct output when I enter 12 and eight 0s. But if I try 47 and eight 0s, all three colors are incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. @ChristianGibbons it was the scanf that needed %lld whereas I only adjusted it for a long instead of a long long. I appreciate the responses and the link. Thank You!